# Generate & send a png or jpg from a Google Form Submission (script attached to Google Sheet that references a Google Doc template)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs, google-forms

I have a google form survey that I send to my app members. I want to include a way for them to create a custom Instagram story post that I'd auto-generate based on their input and email to them to post. The template I use to auto-generate it is a google doc with a placeholder where I plug in their custom input.

My script currently is able to send them the post as a PDF, but that's really frustrating to post on an Instagram story (if not impossible - I spent 20 mins trying to do it).

Is it possible to have the file send as a jpg or png? Or to add a step converting the PDF to a jpg or png?

```js
function onSubmit(e) {
  const rg = e.range;
  const sh = rg.getSheet();
  
  //Get all the form submitted data
  //Note: This data is dependent on the headers. If headers, are changed update these as well.
  const Email = e.namedValues["What's your email address?"][0];
  const Name = e.namedValues["What's your name?"][0];
  const Text = e.namedValues["If you want to make a custom Instagram story sharing what your experience was like, feel free to drop your text here!"][0];
  
  //Build a new story from the template
  //Folder ID (save destination) and file IDs (template ID + new doc ID)
  const StoryFolderID = '1ghiNSWwkUS7WJ5wwnEON5g0-zRueYlfd';
  const StoryFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(StoryFolderID);
  
  const TemplateFileID = '1IJ-i8VeazzmWlxyjyXXKHCLrA3pT1fgu4Zy_m74OgHc';
  const newFilename = 'Story -' + TemplateFileID;
  
  //Make a copy of the template file
  const newTemplateFileID = DriveApp.getFileById(TemplateFileID).makeCopy(newFilename, StoryFolder).getId();;
  
  //Get the body into a variable
  var document = DocumentApp.openById(newTemplateFileID);
  var body = document.getBody();
  
  //Replace all the {{ }} text in the story body
  body.replaceText('{{text}}', Text);

  document.saveAndClose();

// define email variables
var subject = 'Instagram Story';
var img = DriveApp.getFileById("1d2jofSzEsxuUUEw5g-B684AKMALqyy-b").getBlob();



var msgHtml = 
"Hi " + Name + "!" + "<br/>" + "<br/>" +
"Please find your custom story image attached."  ;
var attachment = DriveApp.getFileById(newTemplateFileID);

//send email with the file
GmailApp.sendEmail(Email, subject, msgHtml, {htmlBody: msgHtml, inlineImages: {sampleImage: img}, attachments: [attachment.getAs(MimeType.PDF)]});
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About `Is it possible to have the file send as a jpg or png? Or to add a step converting the PDF to a jpg or png?`, in this case, I thought that [my this blog](https://tanaikech.github.io/2023/01/11/converting-all-pages-in-pdf-file-to-png-images-using-google-apps-script/) might be useful. In this blog, a PDF data is converted to PNG images for every page. When this is reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

In this sample, Drive API is used. So, [please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced?hl=ja#enable_advanced_services).

```js
/**
 * This is a method for converting all pages in a PDF file to PNG images.
 * PNG images are returned as BlobSource[].
 * IMPORTANT: This method uses Drive API. Please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services.
 *
 * @param {Blob} blob Blob of PDF file.
 * @return {BlobSource[]} PNG blobs.
 */
async function convertPDFToPNG_(blob) {
  // Convert PDF to PNG images.
  const cdnjs = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdf-lib/dist/pdf-lib.min.js";
  eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch(cdnjs).getContentText()); // Load pdf-lib
  const setTimeout = function (f, t) {
    // Overwrite setTimeout with Google Apps Script.
    Utilities.sleep(t);
    return f();
  };
  const data = new Uint8Array(blob.getBytes());
  const pdfData = await PDFLib.PDFDocument.load(data);
  const pageLength = pdfData.getPageCount();
  console.log(`Total pages: ${pageLength}`);
  const obj = { imageBlobs: [], fileIds: [] };
  for (let i = 0; i < pageLength; i++) {
    console.log(`Processing page: ${i + 1}`);
    const pdfDoc = await PDFLib.PDFDocument.create();
    const [page] = await pdfDoc.copyPages(pdfData, [i]);
    pdfDoc.addPage(page);
    const bytes = await pdfDoc.save();
    const blob = Utilities.newBlob(
      [...new Int8Array(bytes)],
      MimeType.PDF,
      `sample${i + 1}.pdf`
    );
    const id = DriveApp.createFile(blob).getId();
    Utilities.sleep(3000); // This is used for preparing the thumbnail of the created file.
    const link = Drive.Files.get(id, { fields: "thumbnailLink" }).thumbnailLink;
    if (!link) {
      throw new Error(
        "In this case, please increase the value of 3000 in Utilities.sleep(3000), and test it again."
      );
    }
    const imageBlob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(link.replace(/\=s\d*/, "=s1000"))
      .getBlob()
      .setName(`page${i + 1}.png`);
    obj.imageBlobs.push(imageBlob);
    obj.fileIds.push(id);
  }
  obj.fileIds.forEach((id) => DriveApp.getFileById(id).setTrashed(true));
  return obj.imageBlobs;
}

async function onSubmit(e) {
  const rg = e.range;
  const sh = rg.getSheet();

  //Get all the form submitted data
  //Note: This data is dependent on the headers. If headers, are changed update these as well.
  const Email = e.namedValues["What's your email address?"][0];
  const Name = e.namedValues["What's your name?"][0];
  const Text = e.namedValues["If you want to make a custom Instagram story sharing what your experience was like, feel free to drop your text here!"][0];

  //Build a new story from the template
  //Folder ID (save destination) and file IDs (template ID + new doc ID)
  const StoryFolderID = '1ghiNSWwkUS7WJ5wwnEON5g0-zRueYlfd';
  const StoryFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(StoryFolderID);

  const TemplateFileID = '1IJ-i8VeazzmWlxyjyXXKHCLrA3pT1fgu4Zy_m74OgHc';
  const newFilename = 'Story -' + TemplateFileID;

  //Make a copy of the template file
  const newTemplateFileID = DriveApp.getFileById(TemplateFileID).makeCopy(newFilename, StoryFolder).getId();;

  //Get the body into a variable
  var document = DocumentApp.openById(newTemplateFileID);
  var body = document.getBody();

  //Replace all the {{ }} text in the story body
  body.replaceText('{{text}}', Text);

  document.saveAndClose();

  // define email variables
  var subject = 'Instagram Story';
  var img = DriveApp.getFileById("1d2jofSzEsxuUUEw5g-B684AKMALqyy-b").getBlob();

  var msgHtml =
    "Hi " + Name + "!" + "<br/>" + "<br/>" +
    "Please find your custom story image attached.";

  var attachment = DriveApp.getFileById(newTemplateFileID);
  const imageBlobs = await convertPDFToPNG_(attachment.getBlob());

  //send email with the file
  GmailApp.sendEmail(Email, subject, msgHtml, { htmlBody: msgHtml, inlineImages: { sampleImage: img }, attachments: imageBlobs });
}
```

- When `onSubmit` is run, the PDF data of `attachment.getBlob()` is converted to PNG images and the PNG images are used with `attachments: imageBlobs`.

#### Reference:

- [Converting All Pages in PDF File to PNG Images using Google Apps Script (Author: me)](https://tanaikech.github.io/2023/01/11/converting-all-pages-in-pdf-file-to-png-images-using-google-apps-script/)

Comment: This is magical! It worked like a charm! The only hiccup was that I initially got this error: "Exception: You do not have permission to call UrlFetchApp.fetch. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request
    at convertPDFToPNG_(Create Story:12:20)
    at onSubmit(Create Story:97:28)" so I followed the instructions here to change it from a simple trigger and it worked like a charm -
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58359417/you-do-not-have-permission-to-call-urlfetchapp-fetch  

Thank you so much!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request`, this sample script uses `UrlFetchApp`. If you want to use this script without using `UrlFetchApp`, please directly copy and paste the script of `pdf-lib.min.js` to your Google Apps Script project. By this, this scope is not required to be added.