# My OAuth Scope verified and approved Google Sheets Add-on throwing AppUrlFetch exceptions (scope not approved?)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I am encountering the infamous `Exception: You do not have permission to call UrlFetchApp.fetch. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request` in a **production** context *after* installing my Google Sheets Workspace add-on in a separate test/personal Google sheets environment.

Specifically my application is encountering this issue *after* I finish the end to end installation process of the add-on or upon opening the Sheet with the Add-on, I see an exception in the logs with the `Required permissions` error.

So here's my question: how can I debug this issue? For example, is it an issue where I have a server side script that is **not** a `CUSTOM_FUNCTION` (which is its own `authMode` enum) and is attempting to make an outbound request? (in this case, the outbound request is to my API server to retrieve and save an `API token`)

Or is there some other bug I am hitting on Google Sheet/App script's side where I need to create a workaround for what I am trying to achieve here?

Here is the `event` logged upon `onOpen(e)`:

```json
{"range": {"columnEnd":1,"columnStart":1,
"rowEnd":1,"rowStart":1},
"authMode":"LIMITED",
"source":{},
"user":{"email":"","nickname":""}}
```

(also, Im not sure why both the email and nickname properties are empty, especially since this is a `LIMITED` authMode, and not a `NONE` authMode)

Here is effectively what my code is structured like in the `code.gs` file where this exception issue is encountered:

```js
function onInstall(e) {
   Logger.log(`Install event: ${JSON.stringify(e)}`);
   onOpen(e);
}

function onOpen(e){
// add menu item, regardless of auth mode
  addMenu();

  if(e && e.authMode == ScriptApp.AuthMode.NONE){
    Logger.log(`Auth mode: ${e.authMode}`);
    // prompt user to authorize
    ScriptApp.getAuthorizationInfo(AuthMode).getAuthorizationUrl()
  } else {
    // any other authMode *other* than `NONE`
    tempKey = Session.getTemporaryActiveUserKey();
    var user = Session.getActiveUser();
    var email = user.getEmail();
    var username = user.getUsername();
    const currentTime = new Date().getTime();

    //... abridging other code, but basically we package all this up and...
    // make an outbound request to the API server to get a token
        try{
      // store results of running a function, which itself is a wrapper around a UrlFetchApp request that sets up the payload and headers
      var myApp = createMyApplication();

      // setup a json to store in document properties

      var userOrg = {organization: myApp.data.organization, user: myApp.data.user};

      // save response token in document properties.
      documentProperties.setProperty('APP_AUTH_TOKEN', token);
      documentProperties.setProperty('APP_ORG_DETAILS', JSON.stringify(userOrg) );

      // assign the token variable to the new property of 'APP_AUTH_TOKEN'
      token = orgAuthDetails().token;          

    }catch(err){
      return "Error configuring application user";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And here is my appscript.json manifest file:

```json
{
  "addOns": {
    "common": {
      "name": "My sheets app",
      "logoUrl": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/__PIC_ID__",
      "layoutProperties": {
        "primaryColor": "#B8136C"
      }
    },
    "sheets": {
      "homepageTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "onOpen"
      }
    }
  },
  "timeZone": "America/New_York",
  "dependencies": {
    "enabledAdvancedServices": [
      {
        "userSymbol": "Sheets",
        "serviceId": "sheets",
        "version": "v4"
      }
    ]
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
    "openid",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request"
  ],
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "urlFetchWhitelist": [
    "https://www.mysamplesite.net/"
  ],
  "webapp": {
    "executeAs": "USER_ACCESSING",
    "access": "ANYONE"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the full code you have? Also there is a similar issue here that might help you: [You do not have permission to call UrlFetchApp.fetch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58359417/you-do-not-have-permission-to-call-urlfetchapp-fetch)

Comment: thanks @Logan, I saw that Question from a few years back before posting this one. I can update my question with my appscript.json as well, but the only thing from that post that might be worth trying is removing the `oauthScopes` key which I would be very skeptical about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay answering this question, and it's frankly quite simple, although the implications were not clear to me from the docs, this became clear at runtime:

Even if the corresponding `UrlFetchApp` scope has been approved and properly configured for the application, the underlying google apps script engine will **not** execute any such requests and actively block them UNLESS the `authMode` is `FULL` which it *only* is in these circumstances:

1. upon onInstall(e) event which is relevant in this use-case if the user installs the add-on while in a google sheet from the `Manage -> Add extension` overlay menu
2. upon the user opening and authorizing a (html) sidebar menu item

I solved my issue by updating the code accordingly and the apps script and the `UrlFetchApp` requests are behaving as expected.